# ASP.NET MVC 5, Entity Framework db.savechanges() returns wrong inserted id

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using EF and ASP.NET MVC 5, and when inserting into database using

```
dbcontext.SaveChanges(mymodel)
```

the returned `id` is always "1", however in the SQL database, the inserted record's `id` is "3" (before inserting I deleted the first two records in the database table to clear the table).

Could anyone tell me how to fix this? I feel EF is not update to date with database or am missing any settings to sync both? Many thanks in advance...

My code below...

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    stodoc.StockOutDocument_Serial = srlnum;
    stodoc.StockOutDocument_date = inview.InventoryDate;

    db.StockOutDocuments.Add(stodoc);
    int stodocid = db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: The value returned from the call is the **number of rows affected** - not the new `id` value inserted .....

Comment: that explains, cheers

Answer (score 2):

The ID of the newly created record doesn't come from the SaveChanges call. SaveChanges will update all modified/inserted/deleted records.

Provided you have configured your entity as recognizing it's ID is DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity then to get the newly inserted ID:

```
            stodoc.StockOutDocument_Serial = srlnum;
            stodoc.StockOutDocument_date = inview.InventoryDate;
            db.StockOutDocuments.Add(stodoc);
            db.SaveChanges(); 
            int stodocid = stodoc.stodocid; // Will be populated once SaveChanges is called.
```

If the stodoc.stodocid property is not updated, check that you have configured it in the mapping as an Identity column:

If you used attributes in the entity:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int stodocid { get; set; }
```

or via entity configuration:
EF Core:

```
builder.HasKey(x => x.stodocid);
builder.Property(x => x.stodocid).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
```

EF6:

```
HasKey(x => x.stodocid)
    .Property(x => x.stodocid)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```